# Почему фактический размер SGA_TARGET больше заданного при конфигурации?

Tags: oracle

При создании файла конфигурации *init.ora* параметр `SGA_TARGET` был установлен на 430 MB. Но фактически, после создания БД, команда `show parameters sga_target` показывает 432 MB.

Откуда появились 2 MB? Связано ли это с размером `db_block_size` (8192)? Если нет, то тогда с чем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это связано с гранулярностью размера выделяемой памяти. В [оф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgdba/tuning-system-global-area.html#GUID-8059B22B-0F5F-4492-A6D0-256E6FDF1E59) об этом сказано следующее:

> **SGA Sizing Unit**
> Memory for the buffer cache, shared pool, large pool, and Java pool is allocated in units of granules. If the SGA size is less than 1 GB, then the **granule size is 4MB**. If the SGA size is greater than 1 GB, the granule size changes to 16MB.

Посмотреть, какая гранулярность установлена, можно так:

```sql
SQL> select (bytes/1024/1024) granule_mb from v$sgainfo where name like 'Gran%';

GRANULE_MB
----------
         4
```

То есть, если задать размер не кратный 4MB, округлится в большую сторону:

```sql
SQL> alter system set sga_target=430m scope=memory;
SQL> show parameters sga_target

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
sga_target                           big integer 432M

SQL> alter system set sga_target=436m scope=memory;
SQL> show parameters sga_target

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
sga_target                           big integer 436M
```